# How can I translate the Magento rating codes (Quality, Price, Value)

Tags: magento, translation, magento-1.9

In magento 1.9 in the product page, there is a rating table such as this:
[image]

The question is ... how can I change the literals "Value", "Quality", "Price" to translate them to spanish. I have already checked in the CSV files and they are not there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically there are two ways to change rating table text

1) You can enable translate inline 
   Go to Admin->system->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Translate Inline
   Enabled for Frontend : "yes"

2) Go to Admin->Catalog->Reviews and Ratings->Manage Ratings
   Where you see all three values (Price, Quality, Value)
   open it and  change text

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the rating settings is at **Stores** > Attributes > **Rating**.
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/attributes-rating.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28280551)

Comment: @buzatto: This is more than a link. It’s providing a path to the rating settings. The link is for reference.